# Using SED to with pattern matching to substitute commands

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to locate all of the files that contain `self.vars['stuff']` and replace that text in-line with `self.v.stuff`.

I have tried using: `sed -e "s/self.vars\['/self.v./" -e "s/'\]//"`, but that affects other lines that happen to contain `]` as well...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a backreference. This works in sed, assuming you only use single-quotes for the keys:

```
s/self\.vars\['\([^]]\+\)'\]/self.v.\1/g
```

Comment: It would be better to use here `[^']*` instead of `.*`

Comment: @Igor, I caught that around the same time as you. It should work correctly now.

Comment: `[^']*` would be better, because you variant will not work in this case: `vars['a]b']`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the regular expression would be correcter anyway

Comment: @Igor, it would be more correct for expressions like `vars['a]b']` to remain as they are because that would only throw a key error, as opposed to a syntax error. It might not even throw a key error if `self.vars` and `self.v` coexist.

Comment: This worked! But I'm having trouble understanding how the backreference works. Where does the match for the \1 come from?

Comment: @trinth, the backreference is defined by the escaped parentheses `\(` and `\)`.